# Invalid Flag when adding .JAR to classpath

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I'm still very new to Java as a whole, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a .JAR to my class path.

Here is my javac line thats causing the issue.

```
javac -d %PRAC_BIN% -sourcepath %PRAC_SRC% -cp %PRAC_BIN% %PRAC_LIB%\* %PRAC_SRC%\*.java
```

Inside P03.jar is a the package acsse.csc2a containing three .java files with their respective .class files.

When I run the .bat file, I receive `error: invalid flag: ..\lib\P03.jar`. How do I fix this?

Comment: the value of the `-cp` parameter needs to be one long string, separated using either colon or semicolon: https://howtodoinjava.com/java-examples/set-classpath-command-line/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when classpath  has one or more directories , they should separated by  platform specific classpath separator char  for windows ;  and linux :

changing

```
-cp %PRAC_BIN% %PRAC_LIB%\*
```

to

```
-cp %PRAC_BIN%;%PRAC_LIB%\*
```

should work